# MySql : Get user details using nested relational table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database

Show below tables `users`, `stu_master`, `stu_info`, `emp_master` and `emp_info`.

**users**

[image]

**stu_master**

`stu_master_user_id` = `users.user_id`

[image]

**stu_info**

`stu_info_id` = `stu_master.stu_master_stu_info_id`

[image: ![enter image description here]

**emp_master**

`em_user_id` = `users.user_id`

[image]

**emp_info**

`emp_info_id` = `emp_master.em_emp_info_id`

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have get user first name or last name using above 5 tables with single query;

I have main two types of user one is `Student` and another is `Employee` its login details store in single table its name is `Users`. However I store first/last name related details store in two different table based on user type. if user type is **S**. I will get first/last name in `stu_info` using `stu_master` table because `user_id` relation its available in stu_master table other wise user type is `E`, Get first/last name in `emp_info` using `emp_master` table because `user_id` relation in emp_master table.

### My table relations :

- For Student =  Users->stu_master->stu_info,
- For Employee =  Users->emp_master->emp_info,

I have try below query however not get expected results.

```
SELECT user_id as UserId, stu_first_name as FirstName, stu_last_name as LastName, user_type as UserType FROM `users`  
    LEFT JOIN stu_master tsm ON (stu_master_user_id = user_id AND `user_type` = 'S')
    LEFT JOIN stu_info tsi ON (tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id = tsi.stu_info_id)

UNION ALL

SELECT user_id as UserId, emp_first_name as FirstName, emp_last_name as LastName, user_type as UserType FROM `users`  
    LEFT JOIN emp_master tem ON (em_user_id = user_id AND `user_type` = 'E')
    LEFT JOIN emp_info tei ON (tem.em_id = tei.emp_info_id)

WHERE `user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The above query return `all student` and `all employee`. 
show below output

[image: ![enter image description here]

I get first/last name only given id (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) using any single query.

Please give me any type of single query to achieve my requirement or modified my above query.

Comment: So, what is your problem and what do you ask?

Comment: You must put `Where` clause to the two queries or use parentheses with outer `Select`.

Comment: @wajeeh i use only `Where` clause to the single queries not both queries

Comment: You are not clear. Are you using "=>" to describe your foreign keys? What are you trying to say with the bullets, "=" and "->"? What is your query supposed to do? What is the expected output for some example input? Please read about MCVEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close, and you don't even need the union.

Here's three ways one using a case statement and one using NVL(), and one using an inline view (If you are restricted from changing the table structures, I would use the inline view, it 'should' preform the best. however, if the list of users you want to grab is sufficiently large, you may want to add additionally copies of your where clause to be inside each select statement of the inline view).

```
SELECT `user_id` as UserId
, (CASE WHEN `user_type` = 'S' THEN `stu_first_name`
 WHEN `user_type` = 'E' THEN `emp_first_name`  
END) as FirstName
, (CASE WHEN `user_type` = 'S' THEN `stu_last_name` 
      WHEN `user_type` = 'E' THEN `emp_last_name`  
 END) as LastName
, user_type as UserType 
FROM `users`  
LEFT JOIN stu_master tsm ON (stu_master_user_id = user_id AND `user_type` = 'S')
LEFT JOIN stu_info tsi ON (tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id = tsi.stu_info_id)
LEFT JOIN emp_master tem ON (em_user_id = user_id AND `user_type` = 'E')
LEFT JOIN emp_info tei ON (tem.em_id = tei.emp_info_id)
WHERE `user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);



SELECT `user_id` as UserId
, NVL(`stu_first_name`,`emp_first_name`) as FirstName
, NVL(`stu_last_name`,`emp_last_name`) as LastName
, user_type as UserType 
FROM `users`  
LEFT JOIN stu_master tsm ON (stu_master_user_id = user_id AND `user_type` = 'S')
LEFT JOIN stu_info tsi ON (tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id = tsi.stu_info_id)
LEFT JOIN emp_master tem ON (em_user_id = user_id AND `user_type` = 'E')
LEFT JOIN emp_info tei ON (tem.em_id = tei.emp_info_id)
WHERE `user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

SELECT `user_id` as UserId
, `FirstName` as FirstName
, `LastName`  as LastName
, `user_type` as UserType 
FROM `users`  
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 'S' as user_type
, stu_master_user_id as user_id
, stu_first_name as FirstName
, stu_last_name  as LastName
FROM stu_master tsm
INNER JOIN stu_info tsi ON (tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id = tsi.stu_info_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E' as user_type
, em_user_id as user_id
, emp_first_name as FirstName
, emp_last_name  as LastName
FROM emp_master tem 
INNER JOIN emp_info tei ON (tem.em_id = tei.emp_info_id)
) `User_info` USING (user_id, user_type)
WHERE `user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
;
```

Below is the code I used to create the dummy tables in sqlfiddle.com

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` int, `user_type` varchar(1))
;
insert into users VALUES (1,'A');
insert into users VALUES (2,'E');
insert into users VALUES (3,'E');
insert into users VALUES (4,'S');
insert into users VALUES (5,'S');
insert into users VALUES (6,'S');

CREATE TABLE stu_master
    (`stu_master_id` int,`stu_master_stu_info_id` int,`stu_master_user_id` int)
;

insert into stu_master VALUES (1,1,4);
insert into stu_master VALUES (2,2,5);
insert into stu_master VALUES (3,3,6);
insert into stu_master VALUES (4,4,7);
insert into stu_master VALUES (5,5,8);

CREATE TABLE stu_info
    (`stu_info_id` int,`stu_first_name` varchar(10),`stu_last_name` varchar(10))
;

insert into stu_info VALUES (1,'Student','One');
insert into stu_info VALUES (2,'Student','Two');
insert into stu_info VALUES (3,'Student','Three');
insert into stu_info VALUES (4,'Student','Four');
insert into stu_info VALUES (5,'Student','Five');


CREATE TABLE emp_master
    (`em_id` int,`em_emp_info_id` int,`em_user_id` int)
;
insert into emp_master VALUES (1,1,2);
insert into emp_master VALUES (2,2,3);
insert into emp_master VALUES (3,3,736);
insert into emp_master VALUES (4,4,737);
insert into emp_master VALUES (5,5,738);

CREATE TABLE emp_info
    (`emp_info_id` int,`emp_first_name` varchar(10),`emp_last_name` varchar(10))
;
insert into emp_info VALUES (1,'Employee','One');
insert into emp_info VALUES (2,'Employee','Two');
insert into emp_info VALUES (3,'Employee','Three');
insert into emp_info VALUES (4,'Employee','Four');
insert into emp_info VALUES (5,'Employee','Five');
```

Answer (score 3):

Well directly if you want all the students and all the employers from your current schema you aren't far off:

```
   SELECT tu.user_id as UserId,
          tsi.stu_first_name as FirstName,
          tsi.stu_last_name as LastName,
          tu.user_type as UserType 
     FROM users tu 
LEFT JOIN stu_master tsm 
       ON tsm.stu_master_user_id = tu.user_id 
LEFT JOIN stu_info tsi 
       ON tsi.stu_info_id = tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id
    WHERE tu.user_type = 'S'

    UNION ALL

   SELECT tu.user_id as UserId,
          tei.emp_first_name as FirstName,
          tei.emp_last_name as LastName,
          tu.user_type as UserType 
     FROM users tu 
LEFT JOIN emp_master tem 
       ON tem.em_user_id = tu.user_id 
LEFT JOIN emp_info tei 
       ON tei.emp_info_id = tsm.em_emp_info_id
    WHERE tu.user_type = 'E'
```

In your query you put the user_type condition in the LEFT JOIN, so a record is still returned for the other type (with NULLed names). Your WHERE is also only applied to the second SELECT.

If you want to put a condition on both SELECTS you'll need to duplicate it as two WHEREs or wrap the two UNIONed statements in an outer SELECT with a WHERE.

---

**Other options**

Assuming that there are no missing/duplicate info records for employees or students, you could actually change those LEFT JOINs to straight JOINs and drop the WHEREs:

```
SELECT tu.user_id as UserId,
       tsi.stu_first_name as FirstName,
       tsi.stu_last_name as LastName,
       tu.user_type as UserType 
  FROM users tu 
  JOIN stu_master tsm 
    ON tsm.stu_master_user_id = tu.user_id 
  JOIN stu_info tsi 
    ON tsi.stu_info_id = tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id
 /* WHERE tu.user_type = 'S' /* Optional */ 

 UNION ALL

SELECT tu.user_id as UserId,
       tei.emp_first_name as FirstName,
       tei.emp_last_name as LastName,
       tu.user_type as UserType 
  FROM users tu 
  JOIN emp_master tem 
    ON tem.em_user_id = tu.user_id 
  JOIN emp_info tei 
    ON tei.emp_info_id = tsm.em_emp_info_id
 /* WHERE tu.user_type = 'E' /* Optional */
```

In fact you could go as far as:

```
SELECT tsm.stu_master_user_id as UserId,
       tsi.stu_first_name as FirstName,
       tsi.stu_last_name as LastName,
       'S' as UserType 
  FROM stu_master tsm 
    ON tsm.stu_master_user_id = tu.user_id 
  JOIN stu_info tsi 
    ON tsi.stu_info_id = tsm.stu_master_stu_info_id

 UNION ALL

SELECT tem.em_user_id as UserId,
       tei.emp_first_name as FirstName,
       tei.emp_last_name as LastName,
       'E' as UserType 
  FROM emp_master tem 
    ON tem.em_user_id = tu.user_id 
  JOIN emp_info tei 
    ON tei.emp_info_id = tsm.em_emp_info_id
```

---

**Honestly though, I think you could revisit your schema.** You have a number of strange things going on.

Presumably an employee/student can only have one info record, so is there a need for the many-to-many style linking tables (emp_master/student_master)?

You could actually use the user_id as both the PK and FK to users in the emp_info/student_info tables:

- student - user_id (PK and FK to users), first_name, last_name, ...
- employee - user_id (PK and FK to users), first_name, last_name, ...

Then your query could be:

```
SELECT tu.user_id, ts.first_name, ts.last_name, tu.user_type
  FROM users tu
  JOIN student ts
    ON ts.user_id = tu.user_id
/* WHERE tu.user_type = 'S' /* Optional */        
 UNION ALL
SELECT tu.user_id, te.first_name, te.last_name, tu.user_type
  FROM users tu
  JOIN employee te
    ON te.user_id = tu.user_id
/* WHERE tu.user_type = 'E' /* Optional */
```

or:

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, 'S' AS user_type
  FROM student
 UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, 'E' AS user_type
  FROM employee
```

It's also worth asking if you have considered moving the common fields first_name and last_name up into the users table itself:

```
- users - user_id, user_type, first_name, last_name
```

Then ultimately you are left with:

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, user_type  
  FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare where condition in both join because you are joining  user table with left join and your student and employee table at right side. If you do not compare where condition in both left join it will make separate left with two table and then UNION them. So you will get unnecessary record from single where condition.

```
SELECT `username`, `user_id` FROM users
LEFT JOIN (select stu_first_name as username, stu_master_user_id from `stu_info` 
LEFT JOIN stu_master ON stu_master_stu_info_id = stu_info_id) st ON st.stu_master_user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE `user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND user_type = 'S'
UNION
SELECT `username`, `user_id` FROM users
LEFT JOIN (select emp_first_name as username, em_user_id 
from `emp_info` 
LEFT JOIN emp_master ON em_emp_info_id = emp_info_id) emp ON emp.em_user_id = users.user_id  
WHERE `user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND user_type = 'E'
```